# Resource files are sometimes packaged by Maven, sometimes not

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a project 'P' in Eclipse, its location is outside the Eclipse workspace. There is a resource file: Project_location\src\java\resources\the_file.properties. After launching (in command line)

```
mvn clean install
```

The resource file is packaged in the jar and can be found in Project_location\target\classes\resources\the_file.properties.

From the Eclipse Project Explorer I have copied this project to create 'P_copy' which lies in the Eclipse workspace. If I launch the same Maven command, the resource file is not packaged.

I have compared the projects folder contents, I haven't found any difference that may explain the different packaging behaviour.

What could explain this difference?

In case it is relevant, these lines come from the pom.xml:

```
<build>
   (...)
   <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>      
   (...)
</build>
```

EDIT
After lots of testing I could not even determine a procedure to reproduce the problem at each time.
Sometimes it even seemed that the fact that Eclipse is started had an influence on the packaging, even when mvn is launched in Windows cmd.

Comment: as a standard (convention over configuration) guide: in maven, resources files should be under `src/main/resources` (convention) or any value provided under `build>resources>resource>directory` (configuration). In your case, on second run anything else is fine except this specific copy?

Comment: I know that this project doesn't exactly follows Maven conventions, I can't change the structure (legacy stuffs). There is no 
    build>resources>resource>directory
that includes the folder 'Project_location\src\java\resources\' (I have also checked the effective pom). Knowing that, the file shouldn't be packaged. But it is, and I'd like to know why.

Comment: I made another test: I made a second copy of 'P', in the same directory. Running mvn install doesn't package the resource. It means that the project location is not what makes the difference. I now have two identical projects, located in the same folder, for which mvn install behave differently...

Comment: the file is probably packaged as java code (or java resources) and not project resources (which classpath wise would probably mean the same). The second test was a good finding, which is still weird, some other difference relies somewhere else. Did you run a `mvn clean` or simply a `mvn install`?

Comment: I run 'mvn clean install' for both projects. I confirm that the classpaths are identical. How do we flag a source as a project resource / java resource ?

Comment: resources should be placed under `src/main/resources`, they will be part of the classpath automatically, handled by maven. Check if that changes something, although the whole double behavior is still weird and unrelated to this change, imho

Comment: I haven't found any exact explanation. I will just retain that it can be too hard to fight for a suitable packaging configuration when the project structure doesn't follow the Maven conventions.